# Audio of DV video files is corrupted

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc-media-player

I have .dv files which I have recorded from DV tapes with iMovie. The formats are as follows:

```
Stream #0:0: Video: dvvideo, yuv420p, 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], 28800 kb/s, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le, 32000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1024 kb/s
Stream #0:2: Audio: pcm_s16le, 32000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1024 kb/s
```

On my Mac, the files play just fine in QuickTime Player. But in VLC, while the video works fine, there are high pitched screeching noises, while the original audio can be faintly heard in the background. If I select "Audio -> Audio Channels -> Left" in the VLC menu, the sound problem disappears. I notice there are two stereo streams in the file, which seems odd.

Question 1. If this is a problem with my files and not VLC, is there any ffmpeg command I can run on the command line to repair the files?

Question 2. If this a VLC bug has to be fixed by the VLC developers, how many months can I expect to wait for a solution if I report it?

Comment: Are you using the most recent VLC? Can you provide a small sample file? You can create a small file with `dd` (OS X has `dd`, right?): `dd if=input.dv of=output.dv bs=1024 count=30000`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your recorder adds a timecode in second audio stream. You can either uncheck `Audio -> Audio Track` playback in vlc OR remove that stream with ffmpeg. Example is from question below.

`ffmpeg -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -acodec copy -vcodec copy -i original.dv dv_without_2nd_track.dv`

more about stripping audio ->
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6402/how-to-remove-an-audio-track-from-an-mp4-video-file

Comment: I doubt ffmpeg will allow 32000 Hz audio in DV. ffmpeg only supports 2ch/48kHz/PCM, although there are other variants in the DV specifications. Also, you're applying your options to the input (options before `-i` are input options) although ffmpeg can often assume you're wanting them to be applied to the output.